# Why does layer.getSource().getExtent() need a timeout before it works?

Tags: openlayers

[using OL 4.6.4] I need my website to zoom into the extents of a newly loaded layer (Vector from GeoJSON). If I just use `mapView.fit(myLayer.getSource().getExtent())` right after `map.addLayer(myLayer)` I get an assertion error: *"Uncaught - Object { message: "Assertion failed. See https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/doc/errors/#25 for details.", code: 25, name: "AssertionError", stack: "" }"*

It works when I wait with the call for about 1 sec by putting it in a time-out thus:

```
setTimeout(function () {
        //calculate extent of loaded data and fit:
        mapView.fit(country_provinces.getSource().getExtent());
    }, 1000);
```

But that seems stupid and it's documented nowhere that it is necessary. Is there a proper solution to zooming into a recently uploaded layer?

Full code:

```
var navMap;

/*-- Initialization function --*/
function init() {
    
    //define map object & link to placeholder div:
    navMap = new ol.Map({target: "map_container"});
    // define layer as tiled map:
    osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        // load OSM (a connector predefined in the API) as source:
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });
    // add layer to map:
    navMap.addLayer(osmLayer);
    // create a map view:
    mapView = new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([0, 0], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 2
    });
    navMap.setView(mapView);

    navMap.addControl(new ol.control.Zoom());
    navMap.addControl(new ol.control.MousePosition({
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4)
        })
    );

    var prov_style = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'MediumPurple',
            width: 2
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(147, 112, 219, 0.2)'
        })
    });

    country_provinces = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: '../services/provinces.py',
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
                defaultDataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
                projection: 'EPSG:3857'
            })
        }),
        style: prov_style,
        name: 'Country Provinces'
    });
    navMap.addLayer(country_provinces);
    mapView.fit(country_provinces.getSource().getExtent());
    // run a timer (1 sec), in case .getExtent() doe snot work yet:
    setTimeout(function () {
        //calculate extent of loaded data and fit:
        mapView.fit(country_provinces.getSource().getExtent());
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data needs to be loaded from the url before an extent can be calculated.  The source will fire a `addfeature` event for each feature read and `change` event after all the features have been added, so instead of a timeout you could use

```
country_provinces.getSource().once('change', function () {
        mapView.fit(country_provinces.getSource().getExtent());
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense & works like a charm!